# Interactively look up macro definitions

Tags: tex-core

In a TeX document, the primitive command `\show` will print out the current definition of a macro one level deep (it won't (and can't?) reduce to primitives).
This comes with the restriction of actually being in the document itself, having to typeset and re-typeset over and over, and sifting through log messages (which, even with a bare-bones file, isn't nothing).

Is there a way to run a TeX session interactively such that I can

```
$ latex
> \documentclass{article}
blah blah blah

> \show\list
#1#2->\ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax \@toodeep \else \global \advance \@listdepth \@ne \fi 
\rightmargin \z@ \listparindent \z@ \itemindent \z@ \csname @list\romannumeral \the 
\@listdepth \endcsname \def \@itemlabel {#1}\let \makelabel \@mklab \@nmbrlistfalse 
#2\relax \@trivlist \parskip \parsep \parindent \listparindent \advance \linewidth -
\rightmargin \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin \advance \@totalleftmargin \leftmargin 
\parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth \ignorespaces .

> ...
```

interactively?

Comment: I don't really understand. You've executing `latex` from the command line, loaded the `article` document class and entered `\show\list`. Is this being interactive? If so, then you've actually done all of that. Or what do you mean by *interactive*? Moreover, certain macros are only available from "within the document", since the `\documentclass` loads a number of things.

Comment: The example is contrived; when I try it, I get all sorts of errors that I can't make sense of. (I've also never done an interactive session before, at least not with success.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At some point you need an interactive prompt. You can get such a prompt by an error or the show functions (`\show`, `\showthe`, `\showbox`). The interface of the interactive prompt is quite basic, but additional stuff can be added after using action `i`, example session for file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\show\list
```

LaTeX will stop at `\show\list`, the stuff after `?` is inserted by the user
interactively:

```
$ latex test
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 77 languages loaded.
(/home/one/tl/tldevsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/one/tl/tldevsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
> \list=macro:
#1#2->\ifnum \@listdepth >5\relax \@toodeep \else \global \advance \@listdepth 
\@ne \fi \rightmargin \z@ \listparindent \z@ \itemindent \z@ \csname @list\roma
nnumeral \the \@listdepth \endcsname \def \@itemlabel {#1}\let \makelabel \@mkl
ab \@nmbrlistfalse #2\relax \@trivlist \parskip \parsep \parindent \listparinde
nt \advance \linewidth -\rightmargin \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin \advance 
\@totalleftmargin \leftmargin \parshape \@ne \@totalleftmargin \linewidth \igno
respaces .
l.2 \show\list

? i\makeatletter\show\@listdepth
> \@listdepth=\count34.
<insert>   \makeatletter\show\@listdepth

l.2 \show\list

? i\showthe\@listdepth
> 0.
<insert>   \showthe\@listdepth

l.2 \show\list

?
```

Nevertheless some care is needed:

- Catcodes: The current catcode settings might not be known, here `@` has catcode 12, `\makeatother` changes the catcode of `@` to be used inside macro names. Otherwise `\csname` can be used:

  ```
  \expandafter\show\csname @listdepth\endcsname
  ```
- Depending on the current context, inserting stuff might break or confuse things. For example, in a verbatim context, macros cannot be inserted as macros.